# Surd Manipulations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, irrational-numbers

If a=$-\sqrt {99}+\sqrt {999}+\sqrt {9999}$

b=$-\sqrt {99}-\sqrt {999}+\sqrt {9999}$

c=$-\sqrt {99}+\sqrt {999}-\sqrt {9999}$

Then $\displaystyle\sum_\limits{cyc} \frac{a^4}{(a-b)(a-c)}$ equals??

I first individually calculated (a-b), (b-c), (c-a) and tried to simplify the sum. However, I couldn't do it. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$a^4(b-c)+b^4(c-a)+c^4(a-b)$$

$$=ab(a^3-b^3)-c(a^4-b^4)+c^4(a-b)$$

$$=(a-b)\{ab(a^2+ab+b^2)-c(a+b)(a^2+b^2)+c^4\}$$

$$=\cdots$$

$$=-(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca)$$

Alternatively, if $f(a,b,c)=a^4(b-c)+b^4(c-a)+c^4(a-b)$

Clearly, $f(a,a,c)=0\implies a-b$ is a factor

Similarly, $(b-c)(c-a)$ are also factors

As $f(a,b,c)$ is symmetric about $a,b,c$

$$f(a,b,c)=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(p(a^2+b^2+c^2)+q(ab+bc+ca))$$

Compare the coefficients of $a^4$ to find $p=-1$

Can you find $q=-1?$

Now $a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca=(a+b+c)^2-3(ab+bc+ca)$